# Accessing MySQL connection statements in other pages

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using same MySQL Connection in different PHP pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261624/using-same-mysql-connection-in-different-php-pages)

This is completely new to me, as it stands i have my connect statements on each page in my PHP system. is there a way that i can store this in another, dedicated file and call on this in each page as opposed to including the hard code in each PHP file? could anyone point me in the right direction for tutorials or explain how this works?

Thanks

Comment: Try this way http://www.novaksblog.com/2007/10/02/database-connection-with-php/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the connection information in a file, and use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) in all the other pages.

- Make sure you use .php as extension for the file you're gonna include.
- For security reasons, it is advised to keep the file out of your webroot (one map up is better).
- In case you haven't familiarized yourself with it already, try looking into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of the usual mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 1):

[include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
[include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
[require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
[require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

- The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.
- require is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error.